# Radio buttons with different names into local storage

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a huge form with many radio buttons and I'm using sisyphus.js to local storage all fields. Problem is if a set of radio buttons have the same name it will result in adding a key value for only the last radio button. Earlier I was assisted and was successful in getting radio buttons with different names to uncheck the previously selected one, now I'm stuck with the local storage not saving.

```
function radioUncheck(){
        document.forms.myform.radioa.checked = false;
        document.forms.myform.radiob.checked = false;
        document.forms.myform.radioc.checked = false;
        document.forms.myform.radiod.checked = false;
        document.forms.myform.radioe.checked = false;
        document.forms.myform.radiof.checked = false;

        this.checked = true;

        document.forms.myform.radioa.onclick = radioUncheck;
        document.forms.myform.radiob.onclick = radioUncheck;
        document.forms.myform.radioc.onclick = radioUncheck;
        document.forms.myform.radiod.onclick = radioUncheck;
        document.forms.myform.radioe.onclick = radioUncheck;
        document.forms.myform.radiof.onclick = radioUncheck;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because radio button with the same name are in the same group, representing a single key-value pair as far as HTML is concerned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: so how would you store the first second or third in a group?

Comment: why do you need to store static html elements? Isn't the user's choice that you are interested in storing and retrieving?

Comment: well yes the users choice.. if the user picks the second or third radio button i would like it to still appear when the user closes his browser and reopens it.

Comment: hmmm, I'm beginning to think we got a misunderstanding. Can you provide a working jsFiddle with some of your actual code? The function you provided makes little sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbe81zbe/ is pretty much the setup i have for multiple sections.

Comment: Ok, first of all, how can you use sisyphus if you don't even include jQuery? Second, your function does nothing, since it doesn't return anything and anyway it stores the results in three different variables (why??). Third, if you add jQuery and sisyophus there's no reason why it shouldn't work. Have you tried? You'll have to try locally, sisyphus doesn't work in jsFiddle.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i am not unchecking the radio buttons as previously posted as i have it working with local storage im unable to rerun the function when the local storage re gets the value for the radio. Meaning i click the rdio button and there an onclick event, when i reload the page my radio button is checked again but the function does not run or is not being calculated. Sorry if this is a new problem entirely is there a way to achieve my goal?? I dont know why jfiddle doesnt work it looks right, either way can you show me the format to achieve my goal?

Comment: ask another question, comments are only meant to be about the answer (and thus the question) above.